# Python Selenium keep chrome open between tests

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, testing

I have a class with few tests, for example:

```
class Example(Environment)
   def test1(self):
   def test2(self):
   def test3(self):
   def test4(self):
```

and class environment with setup and teardown methods

```
class Environment(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        options_for_console_log = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        options_for_console_log['loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=options_for_console_log)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def tearDown(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.close()
```

After every test chrome reopens, but i want to run it in one session. How can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setUp` and `tearDown` are called before and after every test method. If you want `driver` to persist between tests move the relevant code to [`setUpClass`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) and [`tearDownClass`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDownClass):

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    options_for_console_log = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    options_for_console_log['loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}
    cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=options_for_console_log)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.driver.close()
```

Just make sure that all the test cases are independent and standalone.