# How to avoid login each time with Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code to login in a website.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get ("https://examplesite.com")

driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("MyUsername")
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("MyPassword")
```

I do some clicks in that homepage and then a second page `https://secondpage.com/some/text` is opened in a different tab. I need to make some automation testing 
in this second page but if I try to work directly in second page changing in my above code from this

```
driver.get ("https://examplesite.com")
```

to this

```
driver.get ("https://secondpage.com/some/text")
```

I'm being redirected to first page `https://examplesite.com` to login again.

I´ve tried to pass the credentials directly in `get` command like this:

```
driver.get ("https://MyUsarname:MyPassword@secondpage.com/some/text")
```

but the same happens and I'm redirected to the login page.

Is there a way to run the script directly in second page without need to login each time I test something?
Maybe mantain in memory Selenium that I´m already logged in?

Thanks for any help

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055518/python-selenium-keep-chrome-open-between-tests

Comment: @benjamin-james Hi Benjamin. I´m very new to Python and classes and things like that. Thanks for share that link, but may you show me please how must be use the setUp and Teardown classes of that link? how to include them in my code?